# Retrieve name and address of employees working in department

Tags: sql, database, merge, oracle11g

I have two tables that I need to query data from that are laid out below:

```
EMPLOYEE (FNAME,MINIT,LNAME,SSN(PK),ADDRESS,DEPARTMENTNUM(FK-DEPARTMENT))
DEPARTMENT (DNAME,DEPARTMENTNUM(PK))
```

I need to look up the FNAME,MINIT,LNAME by using the DNAME from the DEPARTMENT TABLE.

Also, I was wondering how to merge the three (FNAME,MINIT,LNAME) to simply become NAME.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT D.DNAME,E.FNAME+' '+E.MINIT+' '+E.LNAME as NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN
DEPARTMENT D ON E.DEPARTMENTNUM=D.DEPARTMENTNUM
```

Comment: That returned the error message ORA-01722: invalid number.

Comment: @ Raging Bull I tried the query below and it returned (DNAME,FNAME,MINIT,LNAME). Looks good. Thank you.

`SELECT D.DNAME,E.FNAME,E.MINIT,E.LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN
DEPARTMENT D ON E.DNO=D.DNUMBER;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONCAT() function

```
select CONCAT(FNAME, " ", MINIT, ".", " ", LNAME) as NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D
ON
E.DEPARTMENTNUM = D.DEPARTMENTNUM
AND DNAME = <your-dept>
```

Comment: That returned the error message ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't clear from your question you were working on Oracle. This works for mysql. For oracle, you need to use nested concat() as in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) link to add more arguments. That's probably why it was throwing "invalid number of arguments".So, Raging bull's approach would be easier then..